# Is it possible to generate a vertx service proxy that references an rx vertx instance?

Tags: rx-java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I'm trying to develop a database service proxy and using an verticle that extends io.vertx.reactivex.core.AbstractVerticle, so that I can use rxJava semantics around database calls.  Problem is, when I code generate the service proxy, I get this:

```
ServiceVertxEBProxy.java:[37,1] a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of io.vertx.core.Vertx
```

The database service is responsible for dealing with the shared dbclient, which I am doing by:

```
    public Single<SQLConnection> getConnection()
{
    JDBCClient dbClient = JDBCClient.createShared( vertx, CONFIG, DATASOURCE );

    return dbClient.rxGetConnection().flatMap( conn -> {
        Single<SQLConnection> connectionSingle = Single.just( conn );
        return connectionSingle.doFinally( conn::close );
    } );
}
```

Is it possible to use @ProxyGen to create a proxy client that references rxJava in the service?

For reference, the interface declares factory methods to instantiate the service by following the vertx.io documention.

```
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;

@ProxyGen
public interface ChatDbService
{
    static ChatDbService create( Vertx vertx )
    {
        return new ChatDbServiceImpl( vertx );
    }

    static ChatDbService createProxy( Vertx vertx, String address )
    {
        return new ChatDbServiceVertxEBProxy( vertx.getDelegate(), address );
    }

}
```

Help and insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The service proxy generation is not able to work with RxJava as it uses the Vert.x asynchronous model. Since you are not posting the `ServiceVertx` interface it is not really possible to give you further advices concerning your application, if you can we can further elaborate.

Comment: The interface here is the source for the generated ServiceVertxEBProxy in the log message, I missed the prefix when I copied the trace. I also left out the @Fluent method definitions, because it was just the factories that cause the build failure.  Being new to vertx+rx, I'm not sure about the plain vert.x model and why it's not asynchronous.  Is that because vert.x uses callback semantics, which is synchronous in the message passing semantics?  The example I posted is just one of several variants that have this compile failure.  I just thought it was a namespace collision, not compatibility.

Comment: ...is there anything I can put in the question to help diagnose, or is the answer just that I can't use a reactive vertx reference in the service interface?  Essentially, I'm doing what the wiki example does; http verticle + db verticle, which I connect with a service proxy.  The http verticle calls the proxy method that is implemented in a ServiceImpl that implements the interface.  Plan was to start the db verticle and instantiate the dBserviceImpl using the factory.  Barring that, I guess I could just use the dbServiceImpl(vertx) constructor directly from the db verticle and bypass the fac?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this this is what you want, but we wanted `@ProxyGen` to generate an Rxified API for us and stumbled upon a solution. We found that you need to include this dependency and then `@ProxyGen` will create a package called `reactivex` with the Rxified generated service.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-rx-java2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```